# I get an error when I try and run my php script. I am not certain why

Tags: php, html

Here is my php,

```
    <?php
      $to = "jacob@codefarms.us, duma@codefarms.us";
      $subject = _POST['name'];
      $content = __POST['content'];
      $headers = _POST['email'];
      if (!$content === "") {
       mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);
        }

     ?>
```

I get this error when I enter in information,

```
   Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in 
/*****/*******/codefarms.us/contact.php on line 5

 Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' in 
 /*****/*******/codefarms.us/contact.php on line 6

 Warning: Illegal string offset 'email' in 
 /*****/*******/codefarms.us/contact.php on line 7
```

I don't understand why I am getting an error. I use hostgator to host my website.

Comment: _POST? RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: I think it should be  $_POST

Comment: someone want to make that an answer? (it fixed it)

Comment: Just close it, This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an underscore "`_`" :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

The method post should start with underscore "`_`"

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['name'] is the correct to access data in the post array.